# How do I write multiple dataframes to one excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I know how to write multiple dataframes to different sheets in one excel.

But now I want to write two different dataframes in one excel horizonally.

For example:

[image]

The only way I know is

```
pd.concat((df1.reset_index() , df2.reset_index(), axis=1).to_excel('1.xlsx')
```

But this is not convenient.

Reason:

1. concat two df would mess the order of columns , have to do re order maually.
2. have to reset index(df1 is datetime index, df2 is custom string index), which would result ugly presentation .
3. adjusting the postion is diffcult, what if I need one dataframe in left and two dataframes placed vertically in right ?

PS: it is just **`inconvenient`** to use `pd.concat` ,  because need much effort to make that excel look beautiful.

I also tried to use `pd.ExcelWriter` which can assign `startcol` :

1. job 1:

   ```
   file_name = 'xxx.xlsx'
   writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='xlsxwriter', 
                       datetime_format='yyyy-mm-dd',
                       date_format='yyyy-mm-dd')
   df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=0 , startcol=0)
   ```
2. job 2

   ```
   file_name = 'xxx.xlsx'
   writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='xlsxwriter', 
                       datetime_format='yyyy-mm-dd',
                       date_format='yyyy-mm-dd')
   df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=0 , startcol=df1.shape[1]+2)
   ```

But this overwrite the excel ....

I hope there is a easy way to write a dataframe in position `startrow, startcol` without overwirting the file ?

Comment: how is concat messing things up.? did you specify axis=1 for concatenating horizontally

Comment: @Sarthak Negi It  reorder the columns by name. You could have a tried.

Comment: What do you mean by overwriting: the file or areas within the spreadsheet?

Comment: @jmcnamara   `pd.ExcelWriter` would overwrite the whole file .... it means only df2 is write to the file.

Comment: @Mithril it shouldn't overwrite the whole file. This [example that I wrote](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_positioning.html) adds 4 dataframes in the same worksheet.

Comment: @jmcnamara Sorry I simplified  the example. Writing excel twice in different jobs would overwrite the excel, please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

Create columns in df1 and df2 with values as row numbers. This way you will retain the order of the two dataframes.

2) Merge the two dataframes on the the columns created in step one

3) Push this to excel

```
df1['key']= df1.reset_index().index

df2['key'] = df2.reset_index().index

pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer',on='key').to_excel('1.xlsx')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code-only answers are frowned upon. Please explain for OP and future readers. And be sure to format code blocks with `{}` icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xlwings: Get the last column of df1 then go two columns further right with `.offset(column_offset=2)` and then insert df2. It's flexible and easy to use (no need to use `pd.concat`):

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd._testing.makeDataFrame()
df2 = pd._testing.makeDataFrame()

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book()
    wb.sheets[0].range("A1").value = df1
    wb.sheets[0].range("A1").expand("right")[-1].offset(column_offset=2).value = df2
    wb.save()
    wb.close()
```